# Adicionar números dentro de input em sequência ao clicar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho esse input

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control form-sm input_digitacao">
```

E tenho esse script

```
$(".numeros_ligacao li a").click(function(){
    digito = $(this).html();
    $(".input_digitacao").val(digito);
})
```

a variavel digito me retorna um unico numero, ao clicar, dentro desse input aparece o numero correspondente, mas eu quero que adicione um atrás do outro, não que substitua como está fazendo. Tem algum modo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É simples, basta fazer desta forma:

```
$(".numeros_ligacao li a").click(function(){
    digito = $(this).html();
    var valor_anterior = $(".input_digitacao").val();
    $(".input_digitacao").val(valor_anterior + "" + digito);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer desta forma também, pegando o valor já existente no `input`:

```js
$(".numeros_ligacao li a").click(function(){
    var digito = $(this).html();
    $(".input_digitacao").val(function(){ return $(this).val()+digito; });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="numeros_ligacao">
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" readonly class="form-control form-sm input_digitacao">
```